# Are some variables in JS stored on the stack instead of the heap?

Tags: javascript, memory, stack, heap-memory

While reading about memory allocation in JS, most articles I have read have talked about the heap being used for storing variables and objects including functions.

However I've seen the odd article like this one https://medium.com/@allansendagi/javascript-fundamentals-call-stack-and-memory-heap-401eb8713204

which mention that simple variables are also stored on the stack. While I thought the stack was just used for keeping track of where the code is and function calls.

Can someone confirm if variables are stored on both the stack and heap or is it just the heap?

Comment: I think the problem is the article you cite and refer by, is to put in succinctly, all over the place. Stack and heap are simple concepts

Comment: `let n = 5` thats "heap".     .....      `Math.floor(n)`  whereby `n`  goes on "stack" so it can be passed to `floor()` which is also on "stack". And the garbage collector's job is to clean up the "heap". The "stack" unwinds itself, so no gc is really needed here. (But I may have this all wrong. This is just my understanding.)

Comment: Before "garbage collection" you had to manually free your "heap" memory allocs. But the "stack" was always automatic on freeing its allocs in old style high level languages. .... (Again, my understanding. E.g. Turbo Pascal, earlier C, and C++ and the like .... Garbage Collection changed things in later times on the "manual" part regarding "heap".)

Comment: As I understand it, any variable declaration goes on the heap where it's value is stored. This isn't the only article I've seen which referred to variables being stored on the stack though so I thought I would ask on this community for a clear answer.

Comment: Much confusion I agree now trying to type an answer to your last reply. The heap stores more permanent values (even if transitory, hence garbage collection). The stack stores variable values from functions that need them passed in by parameters. Since the stack is indeed a "stack data structure", it's LIFO (last in first out) and unwinds itself; those are gc'd without worry.

Comment: By example, `Math.floor(n)` after "floor" does it's work, `n` is no longer needed and immediately the memory alloc'd for that is recouped. Where as, say you have `let h = "hello"` somewhere else in the program. That would need extra logic to say when `h` is irrelevant.

Comment: But it wouldn't be a `let n = 5` that is freed from memory in an early scope, but the copy of `n` that was passed to `Math.floor(n)` that is freed. Objects (and earlier days, pointers) changed it a bit where no memory is freed in terms of the "stack" automatically. This is where terminology of "by reference" comes in. All "by reference" is in "heap" and that's where garbage collection comes in again

Comment: Ok maybe it is complicated. But I just look at the stack as literally a stack of cards or anything, with one rule, LIFO. The heap is more like random access memory type data structure.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, variables themselves are typically stored in one of two locations: the stack or the heap. However, it's important to note that JavaScript is a high-level, garbage-collected language, and the specifics of memory management are often abstracted away from developers.

Here's a brief overview:

1. **Stack:** The stack is used for storing primitive data types and references to objects. When a function is called, a new stack frame is created to store local variables and function parameters. The stack operates in a Last In, First Out (LIFO) manner, making it efficient for managing function calls and local variables. Primitive data types like numbers, booleans, and references to objects are often stored on the stack.
2. **Heap:** The heap is used for storing complex data structures like objects and arrays. Objects are larger and more complex than primitive data types, and they can vary in size during their lifetime. The heap allows dynamic memory allocation and deallocation. References to objects (pointers) are stored in the stack, but the actual object data is stored in the heap.

In JavaScript, variables declared with `let`, `const`, or `var` are initially allocated on the stack if they are primitive types. However, when it comes to objects, the variable holds a reference to the object, and the object itself is stored in the heap.

Here's a simple example:

```js
let num = 42;  // 'num' is stored on the stack
let obj = {   // 'obj' is a reference stored on the stack, pointing to the object in the heap
  key: 'value'
};
```

So, while the variables themselves might be stored on the stack, when dealing with objects or complex data structures, the actual data is stored in the heap, and variables hold references to that data.

You can and should check out this article: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-call-stack-and-heap-memory-in-js-e34bf8d3c3a4